# SQL | How iterate over insert or update statement for performance and keep it secure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-injection

I have service that execute almost non stop the same insert or update statement, and the only thing that changes is the parameters.

Since we are handling a big amount of records, were sending the insert few queries together in each call to the DB.

Sadly the outcome is a 900 lines query that's keep been send to the SQLServer non stop.

I thought of a way to cut the transport and maybe the massive job of parsing a 900 lines query by sending the body once and iterate over the parameters, and I came up with the following query:

```
DECLARE @par VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) 
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT ( '181120104;98415;001;''P357LT'''....) 
OPEN db_cursor  
DECLARE @Iteration INT 
SET @Iteration = 1 
WHILE @Iteration <= 10 
BEGIN 
set @sql=' update [orderItemsHistory] set '
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql=@sql+ '[OrderId]  = ' + @par + ' ,'
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql=@sql+ ' 
[StoreNo]  = ' + @par + ' ,'
.
.
.

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql=@sql+ ' 
[ItemPackTime]  = ' + @par + ' ,'
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql=@sql+ ' 
[TimeToShow] = ' + @par + ' '
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql = @sql +' where '+ @par 
print(@sql); 
exec(@sql); 
if @@rowcount = 0
 begin FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
set @sql='insert into [orderItemsHistory]( [OrderId] , 
[StoreNo] , 
.
.
.
[TimeToShow]) 
 VALUES ('+@par+' )'
print(@sql); 
exec(@sql); 
end 
else 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @par 
SET @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
END
CLOSE db_cursor 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And it's actually works just fine, but it's easy to see that it's opening a big gate for sql injection.

If I'm trying the safer & easier solution, and just use ? and send my params:

```
DECLARE @Iteration INT 
SET @Iteration = 1 
WHILE @Iteration <= 11 
BEGIN 
update [orderItemsHistory] set [OrderId]  = ?, 
[StoreNo]  = ?, 
.
.
.
[TimeToShow] = ? 
 where [orderId]= ? And [StoreNo]= ? And [Position]= ?
 if @@rowcount = 0
 begin insert into [orderItemsHistory]( [OrderId] , 
[StoreNo] , 
.
.
.
[TimeToShow]) 
 Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
)end
SET @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
```

I'm getting the kind of obvious error:

> [err:  In DbCon.Exec(), execCounter:0error : sql: expected 39 arguments, got 702]

anyone have any idea how to work with iteration, in a more secure and efficient way?

Comment: I doubt you need a cursor for this.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: If you're using dynamic SQL you should be using `sp_executesql` and parametrising your statement, not simply injecting the values.

Comment: Where I've done this before I have passed an xml string, then in the proc parsed that into a temp table, then done whatever sql I need from that. You just need to keep the xml size inside size limits. I tend to use single-letter identifiers in the xml to drastically reduce the size.